# How is a connection the same as Morphism between different pullbacks to the first infinitesimal neighbourhood

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

This question arose from the first pages of Delignes Equations Differentielles.

There he defines a connection on a vector bundle $V$ on an complex analytic space $X$ as the following Data:

For all analytic spaces $S$ and pairs $(x,y)$ of $S$-points of $X$ (i.e. Morphisms from $S$ to $X$), such that the morphism $(x,y):S\longrightarrow X\times X$ factors through the first infinitesimal neighbourhood $X_1$ of the diagonal $X_0$: a morphism $\gamma_{x,y}:x^*V\longrightarrow y^*V$ s.t.:

- For all morphisms $f:T\longrightarrow S$ we have $f^*\gamma_{x,y}=\gamma_{xf,yf}$
- $\gamma_{x,x}=\operatorname{id}$

He then claims a little bit further that this is the same as a homomorphism
$\gamma:p_1^*V\longrightarrow p_2^*V$ which induces the identity on $X_0$ and that this is automatically an isomorphism. (Here the $p_i$ denote the projections of $X_1$ to $X$).

For me this sounds like he uses the Yoneda Lemma here to derive this claim, somehow interpreting the definition of a connection as a natural transformation between a representable functor (probably represented by $X_1$?) and another one. I played around with this idea but wasn't able to make it precise, so my question is: Can we, and if yes how, interpret the claim he makes as an application of the Yoneda Lemma?

Comment: I don't think the Yoneda Lemma has anything to do with this. His definition comees ffrom the fact that a having a connection is the same thing as knowing how to do parallel translation along all curves, and that knowing this is the same as knowing how to do it infinitessimally up to first order.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, I'm not sure if I stated the question precisely enough, I meant if the claim he makes follows from his definition by the Yoneda Lemma (I'll edit the question). It would, however, also be interesting for me to understand how exactly his definition relates to parallel transport along curves.

Comment: If you read the next few pages you will see how he arrive at the usual definition of connection.

Comment: The point is that an infinitesimal neighborhood  of the diagonal is just the usual equivalence used to define the jet bundle.

Comment: Hi, was reading the next few pages and tried to understand the relation to the usual definition, this is where the question comes from. I think I can also show by elementary means that the claim he makes is true. Still, I was wondering if this can be shown by using the Yoneda Lemma but was not able to define/isolate the appropriate categories and functors to apply it.

Comment: Regarding the comment from Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, it would be interesting if there is a way to see directly the connection with parallel transport without the "detour" via the more familiar definition of a connection, but maybe that is another question...